# statsmodels.tsa._stl.STL "Unable to determine period from endog"

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I want to get decomposed by statsmodels STL method

my time series data looks like bellow:

```
         success.rate
Date
2020-09-11  24.735701
2020-09-14  24.616301
2020-09-15  24.695900
2020-09-16  24.467051
2020-09-17  24.118799
```

when I put it into STL like

```
STL(sdf, seasonal=20, robust=True)
```

I always get error like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/mnt/d/mywork/test
 STL(sdf,seasonal=20, robust=True)
----> 1 STL(sdf, seasonal=20, robust=True)

statsmodels/tsa/_stl.pyx in statsmodels.tsa._stl.STL.__init__()

ValueError: Unable to determine period from endog
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your time series does not have a known frequency on the index (e.g., `sdf.index.freq` is `None`, then you need to set the period of the seasonality using the `period`. `seasonal` tells STL how many full seasons to use in the seasonal LOWESS but doesn't tell STL how many observations are needed for a full period.

```
from statsmodels.datasets import co2
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import STL
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

data = co2.load(True).data
data = data.resample('M').mean().ffill()

# Remove freq info
data.index = [i for i in range(data.shape[0])]

res = STL(data, period=12).fit()
res.plot()
plt.show()
```

This code produces

[image: STL Demonstration]

Comment: Kevin, this exactly resolves my problem, thanks~

Comment: how to detect the period? Month? Yearly or day?